# How can I make one file that aggregates the data from few different Excel files?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using MS Office 2013 and have eight files in Excel with one table per file. Each of them contains: Product, ref.number, quantity. Each file contains data for products from other month, so product numbers can repeat across files.

I want to make one file in which will be aggregation of all those files, with additional column for date (based on file that data come from). Is there any way to automatic merge all information to one file, or it need to be done manually?

Answer (score -2):

Try using Excel pivot tables.  They allow for consolidating multiple sheets in a single table.  I just a built a test using the help link below and it worked perfectly.  It only took 15 minutes to build the sample, so you might want to try it for starters.  Here is the how to link:

[Consolidating mulitple worskheets](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-PivotTable-report-3ae257d2-ca94-49ff-a481-e9fc8adeeeb5#bm1)